# Url stored in the database

Tags: url, spring-mvc

I learn Spring MVC and I came to a point where I need advice from someone experienced.

Well, so far the reworking of tutorials, URLs I created for "static" in the controllers using the annotation @RequestMapping. But I would like to store all the urls in the database to be able to edit in CMS. How to do it?
Create tables in the database urls (with columns: url, controller) Create a controller that will intercept all urls and based on the current urla retrieve from a database the appropriate controller to be processed?

Good idea? Is there a dedicated solution for this?

Comment: You won't be able to use `@RequestMapping` for this. You'll need your own `HandlerMapping` implementation.

Comment: Can you give an example a solution this issue? Is my suggestion is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this project:

https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router

It isn't exactly what you described, as the URL's are stored in a text file rather than a database, but I think you might still be able to get it to work correctly with your CMS.

Your custom defined routes will look similiar to this:

```
GET     /user/?                 userController.listAll
GET     /user/{<[0-9]+>id}      userController.showUser
DELETE  /user/{<[0-9]+>id}      userController.deleteUser
POST    /user/add/?             userController.createUser
```

This project will make it very easy for you to map URL's to your controllers and change them around in one centralized location.